# ASP.NET Core: redirect issue

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the issue with redirect from http to https:

http:*** => https:***:44345
Is It possible do not show port 44345 in url?

My project configuration:

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57854",
      "sslPort": 44345
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Site": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseFileServer();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Please, advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use port 443 which is the standard HTTPS port. Note however that this usually requires admin privileges, so that's why you usually don't do this on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Only ports 80 and 443 for http and https respectively allow for the port to be omitted in the address. This is because your browser will see http or https and transparently make the request to the port appropriate for that protocol.